# Read a value from a large file after a prefix

Tags: java, string, file

Through Java I have to read a value of *input and output* from a large report file. In the file these values come after a prefix 'From ABC source:' as I have given the file below. The format is fixed. The size of the file is not fixed.

File or string starts here --

```
x

y

z

-***********************************************************************

*                   ** xyx entry   **                         *

-***********************************************************************

result is at 2013-06-22 02:11:06 ( result since 2013-06-06 23:40:03)

From ABC source:

       #                   input  :    30
       #                   output :    40
```

File or string ends here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you open a file for reading text in Java?  If so then write the code to do so.  If not then read the manual/textbook, it is in there.

Can you read the open file character by character?  If so then write the code to do so.  If not then read the manual/textbook, it is in there.

Can you determine if the character you just read is an "F"?  If so then write the code to do so.  If not then read the manual/textbook, it is in there.

Read the characters following an "F" to see if they match "rom ABC source:".  If they don't match then carry on, character by character, looking for an "F".  If they do match, then you have found the right place in your file.

Was that really so difficult?

ETA: If the file is *very* large and things are running too slowly, there are ways to speed up the search.  Best to try the simple serial search first.  If it is fast enough then use it; it makes later code maintenance a lot easier.

Comment: may be he wants to do with api calls like `split("From ABC source")`...but ofcourse here the concern is it's large file...

Comment: Thanks for the answer and time Rossum. It’s really a simplest way.